# Why $\frac{dx^TA}{dx}=A^T$ instead of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

This is a really basic question, but I have spent one hour on it.

> Suppose $A$ is a matrix and each entry of $A$ is not a function $x$,
>   where $x$ is a vector. Then, $$\frac{dx^TA}{dx}=A^T.$$

**Below is my try to prove it:**

$$\frac{dx^TA}{dx}=\frac{d(A^Tx)^T}{dx}=\left(\frac{dA^Tx}{dx}\right)^T=(A^T)^T=A.$$

Frankly, I just do not understand why it's $A^T$ instead of $A$ in the original equation.

Comment: It seems that one result is coherent with numerator layout and the other with denominator layout: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions

Comment: I assume that $A$ is $m \times n$ and $x$ is $m \times 1$, so $x^T A$ is $1 \times n$. Perhaps things are more clear if we take the point of view that the derivative of $f$ at $x$ is a linear transformation that satisfies $f(x + \Delta x) \approx f(x) + L(\Delta x)$. But $f(x + \Delta x) = x^T A + \Delta x^T A$, which reveals that $L(\Delta x) = \Delta x^T A$.

Comment: @EmilioNovati Can we say numerator and denominator have to layout in these ways, because of dimensions?

Comment: It should be possible to clarify this just be looking closely at the definition of $\frac{d}{dx}$. It's not clear exactly what definition is being used in this context. The Jacobian matrix is usually defined for a function $g:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, where $\mathbb R^n$ is the set of all real $n \times 1$ column vectors and $\mathbb R^m$ is the set of all real $m \times 1$ column vectors. But for the function $f(x) = x^T A$, the range is $\mathbb R^{1 \times n}$, which is a space of row vectors. The standard definition of the Jacobian matrix does not apply, so it must be clarified.

Comment: @ChunjingGU: the question cannot be illustrated in a comment. I write an answer that , I hope, can be useful  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between numerator and denominator layout is due to the fact that a linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is represented in different ways if the vectors of the two vector spaces are rows or columns vectors.

If $A_L$ is the matrix that represents the transformation as $ A_L:\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}\to\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$ than the matrix that represents the ''corresponding'' transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{1\times n}\to\mathbb{R}^{1\times m}$  (the same transformation if we think at  $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$) is the transpose $A_L^T$.

In your case the transformation represented by $\vec y=\vec x^T A$ can be thinked as a transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1} \to \mathbb{R}^{1\times m}$.

Using an example with low dimension ( $n=3\;,\; m=2$) to avoid complication in the indices, we can think to a transformation  from $\mathbb{R}^{3\times1}\to\mathbb{R}^{1\times 2}$  that can be represented in the form

$$
\vec y=[y_1\quad y_2]=\vec x^T A=
\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}&A_{21}\\
A_{12}&A_{22}\\
A_{13}&A_{23}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}&A_{21}\\
A_{12}&A_{22}\\
A_{13}&A_{23}
\end{bmatrix}=
$$
$$
=\begin{bmatrix}(A_{11}x_1+A_{12}x_2+A_{13}x_3)&
(A_{21}x_1+A_{22}x_2+A_{23}x_3)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
now,if we want that the derivative is a matrix that operate on a column vector of $\mathbb{R}^{3\times1}$, the derivative must be:
$$
\frac{d \vec y}{d \vec x}=\frac{d (\vec x^T A)}{d \vec x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_1}&
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_2}&
\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x_3}\\
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_1}&
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_2}&
\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x_3}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{11}&A_{12}&A_{13}\\
A_{21}&A_{22}&A_{23}
\end{bmatrix}=
A^T
$$